# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/blah.png") Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

I've seen this error run into a few times in multiple different threads here but although after trying almost all of the mentioned solutions I'm still hitting multiple of these errors within my `heroku logs`.

> It should be noted that I'm using rails 4.2.

The interesting thing is the images within the `HTML` load fine, **however** the images that are attempting to be accessed from my `SCSS` files do not load at all and I hit the following error on those files.

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/roses-right.png"):`

As I've said I've tried multiple solutions including running `rake assets:precompile` both locally and on the heroku server. I've also attempted setting `config.serve_static_files = true` within `config/environments/production.rb` and still no dice. And lastly within my gemfile I do have the following block:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change in your scss to use the sass helpers that the gem provides, like:

```
image-path('roses-right.png')
```

Check the docs at https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#asset-helpers

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, anytime that I try to use one of those helpers I get errors and precompile doesn't work.

Comment: just to be sure, you have the gem 'sass-rails'?

Comment: Yes it's definitely sass-rails

Comment: could you try without double quotes? I had some problems before using double quotes in scss

Comment: That did the trick! However I used something more along the lines of this `background: image-url('header_background.png');`

Answer (score 1):

I had one remaining problem in Rails 5 in production mode using engines as gems with images below /vendor/assets/.. :

- Images are referenced from untouched vendor's css-code (e.g. jquery-ui) and therefore are without any scss conversion code for asset pipeline like "image-path", "image-url", "asset-path" or "asset-url"
- All these vendors images are also precompiled to /public/assets by "rake asset:precompile" if you add this to config/initializers/assets.rb

  ```
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.ico *.gif *.png *.jpg )
  ```
- runtime references from css already uses native image names instead of precompiled hashed names and therefore end up in "no route for ..."

My workaround solution was to copy asset pipeline's objects in /public/assets down to its native names so there are two versions of each file. 
The native and the hashed name.

- Native names are gotten from sprockets manifest file so I mustn't know the real location of these files in gem path
- Copy is done as part of "rake assets:precompile"

Create a file "lib/tasks/precompile.rake"

```
require 'json'
require 'fileutils'

namespace :assets do
  task :precompile do
    puts '####### Task assets:precompile extended in lib/tasks/precompile.rake !'
    puts '####### Add native files to public/assets if requested outside from asset pipeline'

    Dir.glob("public/assets/.sprockets-manifest*.json").each do |fname|
      manifest = IO.read(fname)
      mhash = JSON.parse(manifest)
      mhash['files'].each do |key, value|
        source = "public/assets/#{key}"
        target = "public/assets/#{value['logical_path']}"

        puts "# create #{target}"
        FileUtils.cp(source, target)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This way this cloning code is executed at the end of "assets:precompile" rake task.